# invalid use of static data member in constructor parameter list

Tags: c++11, non-static, data-members

I have a class something like this:

```
class Foo : public Bar {
double v1;
double v2;
...
public:
explicit Foo (double v1_ = 1.0, double v2_ = v1 > 0.0 ? 2.0 : 0.0)
    : v1(v1_), v2(v2_)
{
    // do something
}

// do other things

};
```

but I get the following compile error like so:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member Foo::v1
note: declared here
double v1;
       ^
```

Any suggestions are appreciated to get around this error. Also, please point out the mistake in my code and explain a little so that I can understand better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
explicit Foo (double v1_ = 1.0, double v2_ = v1 > 0.0 ? 2.0 : 0.0)
                                             ^^
```

At the point where you use v1 it does not exist yet.

Unfortunately, you can't use `v1_` at this point either. What you can do instead, is to split the constructor in two versions:

```
// for two arguments
Foo (double v1_, double v2_)
    : v1(v1_), v2(v2_)
{
    // do something
}

// for zero or one argument
explicit Foo (double v1_ = 1.0)
    : Foo(v1_, v1_ > 0.0 ? 2.0 : 0.0)
{
}
```

(here I used delegating constructors feature to avoid code duplication)

Comment: Okay, so probably I should use v1_ there but that gives a different error stating that v1_ was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Yes, you can't make one default argument depending on the other that easy. You are better off with two separate constructors.

Comment: Okay, that looks better actually. But I can't pass `v2_` to second constructor right? I realize if we could then that would bring to the point back to where we started.

Comment: No, you can't. Their signature would be the same then.

Comment: Yeah, in that case this seems like the only way to go. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

When you call the constructor the object doesn't exist yes. It's the constructor that creates and returns it. So you can't refer to `v1` in the arguments of the constructor - there is still no object and no v1.

Comment: Copying my comment from above -- Okay, so probably I should use v1_ there but that gives a different error stating that v1_ was not declared in this scope. I happen to need to check that condition on v1. What should be an alternate approach in this situation?

Comment: Do not give default value for v2, but rather simply do the assignment and logic in the body of the constructor.